# Thermocouple chip & CJC compensation under 0°C

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, thermocouple

We are currently designing a "conditioning" module that takes a couple of sensors (T°, Pressure but also via digital bus) and repeats over CAN / also outputs them in nice and clean analog signals (0-5V) when needed.

Problem is : we are trying to find an analog (the detail is imporant) thermocouple conditioning chip that carries a serious Cold Junction Compensation mechanism.

N.B : we've obviously found the AD595/59x series but they only specify (and guarantee, we've contacted them) for Cold Junction Temperatures above freezing point (0°C). They might work below but we have no firsthand experience with them out of the datasheet so we can't legitimately integrate them.

The other option being to use a Tk-to-digital but we want to avoid that for various reasons.

- Is our only option to use discrete Op-Amps with a CJC mechanism based
  on discretes?
- Have any of you any experience on using these integrated-CJC out of
  specs? the +50°C is fine by us but we need to go below 0°C. What we are really asking ourselves is : what happens when we go below the minimum (0°) ? Does the CJC stop working altogether or does it compensate based on a temperature of 0°?

Thanks for the help,

M

Comment: Can you not warm the chip? It does operate below 0C. Performance is just not specified

Comment: Nope, not a possibility.
The application is a vehicle...

Comment: Vehicle...as in a fuel vehicle with a hot engine?

Comment: You can use opamp and digital sensor for CJC. There are also thermocouple ADC converters with built-in CJC sensor.

Comment: "The other option being to use a Tk-to-digital but we want to avoid that for various reasons", can you elaborate those reasons? Are you projecting an analog or digital device?

Comment: Chances are the ADI part still tries below freezing, but goes off the end of whatever compensation circuit they've designed into the thing -- meaning the further below 0 you go the less accurate it is, and the difference probably varies from chip to chip.

Comment: If you're outputting in both digital and analog, why not do the CJC in software, and feed that number to a DAC?

Comment: Hi all,

Regarding the need for analog, this is for FIT / safety reasons. We are using a comparator to trigger a fault over a certain threshold.
Even though it might seem marginal to some, a completely analog solution for such a simple task is usually more reliable than a digital (for which, the FIT rate of the µC has to be added + possible bugs, memory corruption etc...)

Comment: Hi all, One way that I see doing it would be to simply use a simple precision Op-Amp for the Thermocouple in conjunction with a seperate ambiant T° sensor and do the CJC and 
 linearisation in software.
As I see it, this approach has the advantage of not using any expensive dedicated Tk chip and have negative CJC ability.